# Do you list that you won a competitive funding to attend a conference but couldn't go on a CV?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, conference, cv, visa

I won a funding scholarship from a prestigious research institute to attend a workshop in my field. The funding covers my travel expenses and accommodation but, I won't be able to participate because I couldn't find any vacant visa appointment in my country.

I am very sad already that I won't be able to participate. Anyway, should I list in my CV that I won this funding scholarship? Since winning grants is valuable in an academic CV.

I am a graduate student, looking to pursue graduate studies in the US.

Comment: I also had issues finding Visa slots for an internship. Email the embassy/consulate in your country ASAP explaining your situation and ask them for an appointment. The fact that your stay is fully funded will help your case. It may not work out, but it's definitely worth a try. Don't give up!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list that you won that travel award/scholarship. You do not have to write that you could not travel, but mention it if it comes up in an interview.

Attending a conference is unlikely to be a deciding factor for any hiring decisions.

Answer (score -5):

"There were problems with my visa" is not something that you want to tell a potential employer. They prefer employees who can travel anywhere without problems.

Comment: There were no problems with my visa, I couldn't find a visa appointment in my country. In some countries, one has to apply for a visa appointment first to get their visa application reviewed to be considered.